# my code works in jsfiddle but the event is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This works perfect in jsfiddle but when I place the exact code in my local copy the 'on click' event is not firing.  I have jquery, can't figure out why.  Any thoughts appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/3d867zeu/8/

```
$( ".dropdown-check-list li input" ).on( "click", function() {
  var maxCheckedAllowed = 2;
  var n = $( ".dropdown-check-list li input:checked" ).length;
  if (n == maxCheckedAllowed) {
    $('.dropdown-check-list li input:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.dropdown-check-list li input:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, what's different about your local copy? Any ajax refreshes involved?

Comment: It is identical - no ajax.  I just copy it over and the behavior does not occur.

Comment: Is the element being added to the DOM dynamically? Are you including your jQuery script before the </body> so the DOM has had a chance to load before you start manipulating it? Could be lots of things...

Comment: If you want to cath error, you should bring your original code what make error.

Comment: Something is obviously not the same, either the markup causing the selectors to be incorrect or if you get no error in the console, possibly the code is running before the elements are in the DOM

Comment: jsfiddle will automatically put your code inside `onLoad` (for standard javascript) - you need to wrap your code.

Comment: I do have my code wrapped in document.ready.

Comment: Do you have any HTML loaded via ajax (specifically `dropdown-check-list` or its content)?  (update: looks like you already answered this)

Comment: @Satpal hard to tell, OP states that there's no ajax and that the script is inside `document.ready()` - yet comment on event delegation answer implies one of these is not correct.  If it's just that the script is in `<head>` without `doc ready` then it's not a duplicate (of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below option for your local.

When you create a `$( ".dropdown-check-list li input" )` this click event , that time if your dropdown check box is bind before this click event code is excute then your click is work. But in my case i create a click event using a document , so every time when click is fire on `.dropdown-check-list li input` on this class that time my click event is fire. Hope you understand this explanation.

```
$(document).on( "click",".dropdown-check-list li input", function() {
  var maxCheckedAllowed = 2;
  var n = $( ".dropdown-check-list li input:checked" ).length;
  if (n == maxCheckedAllowed) {
    $('.dropdown-check-list li input:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.dropdown-check-list li input:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works - could you explain why your code works and mine does not?

Comment: This uses delegated events, which you need if your code runs *before* the html is ready - either because the html is loaded after this script has run (hence all the questions in comments about loading via ajax) or because your script is not run in `document.read(function() { .. here .. })` which would be difference between your code and jsfiddle.